# Gradient color effect on CAShapeLayer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to apply gradient colors on CAShapeLayer. For that i write code,

```
-(void)addCircle{
{
    // Drawing code
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(150, 150)
                                                         radius:125
                                                     startAngle:0
                                                       endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180)
                                                      clockwise:NO];


    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [shapeLayer setFrame: self.frame];
    [shapeLayer setPath: [aPath CGPath]];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 30.0f;
    [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    [shapeLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];


    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.0);
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        [colors addObject:(id)[[UIColor colorWithHue:(0.1 * i) saturation:1 brightness:.8 alpha:1] CGColor]];
    }
    gradientLayer.colors = colors;
    [gradientLayer setMask:shapeLayer];

    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

But i got without gradient color output like this,
[image]

I want the final output like this, 
[image]

But my primarily goal is apply gradient effects on CAShapeLayer. Where i'm wrong in my given code stuff?

Comment: **Adding sublayers inside `drawRect:` is definitely wrong.**

Comment: That being said: you seem to be mixing two different drawing approaches. One being custom drawing in drawRect: and one being layers. No matter which approach you choose you will have to do the drawing in a few steps adding shadows and masking the white gradient. Can you please clarify what it is you are having problems with?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, Firstly i very happy on to show me my mistake. I want apply gradient color effects on Red color circle. See my second image, i want to create same effects. Actually i don't know how to create end output meter circle, but i assume the thin whites color on second image is like gradient layer and that why i selected this scenario.

Comment: Now i edited my code. I remove code from draw rect method and add it separate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you're adding `shapeLayer` to the view's layer, but you actually just want to use that as a mask, so you should be adding `gradientLayer` instead.

The next problem will be that `CAGradientLayer` doesn't support radial gradients like the one in your second screenshot. You'll need to do custom drawing to achieve that effect (or just use an image).

Comment: Oh!!!! Second image contain Radial Gradient effect? Now i wonder on how to use image for creating gradient effects.